# Is there anyway to stop TWebBrowser from clearing?

Tags: delphi

Is there anyway to stop TWebBrowser from clearing when I set `Self.Parent := nil;`?
When it gets to that line (which is necessary for a maximizing function), all the TWebBrowsers in my form clears. Why does it do that and what can I do to avoid this?

EDIT:
'Self' is the current form (in this case AnsForm) being shown on the MainForm. 
Previous value of Parent is a Tab in MainForm.
I tried setting `Self.Parent` to something else but the same thing happens.

Comment: What kind of object does `Self` refer to in this context? And what was the previous value of `Parent`?

Comment: `Self` is the current form (in this case `AnsForm`) being shown on the MainForm. Previous value of `Parent` is a Tab in MainForm.

Comment: why do you need to change `parent`?

Comment: It's part of the maximize function. It detaches the form (AnsForm) from the MainForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reassigning the `TWinControl.Parent` property causes that control (in this case, your `TForm` object) to destroy its `HWND` (as a child `HWND` cannot exist without a parent `HWND`), and a new `HWND` is not created until the next time that control's `Handle` property is accessed (if no `Parent` is available by then, an exception is raised).  When a control destroys its `HWND`, all of its child controls, and their child controls, and so on, destroy their own `HWND`s as well.  Without an `HWND`, there is nothing for a control to display, and any content stored in those `HWND`s is lost.  That is why your `TWebBrowser` objects get cleared.

Some components cache their current content in memory when their `HWND` is destroyed and then restore that content when a new `HWND` becomes available, but `TWebBrowser` does not (and cannot) do that.  Your only option in this situation is to manually reload the current URL again.  Otherwise, re-design your UI so the `TWebBrowser` objects do not reside on a parent control whose `Parent` property changes.